How do I organize Oracle Linux yum server repos for Oracle Linux Virtualization Manager
I want to configure Oracle Linux Virtualization Manager on Oracle Linux 8.
OLVM is the UI on top of KVM.
From Oracle's blogpost :

Both Oracle Linux Virtualization Manager and Oracle Linux can be
downloaded, used, and distributed free of charge and all updates and
errata are freely available.

In order to install this, I need tons of packages from different repos hosted here.
The documentations says a lot about enabling repos, but not much about how to add the repos to /etc/yum.repos.d/
Yes, I can do this, but it doesn't change anything before I have the repo-files/repo-sections configured under /etc/yum.repos.d/
dnf config-manager --enable ol8_gluster_appstream ol8_baseos_latest ol8_appstream ol8_ovirt45

Is there a best way to download repos to list of repos (dnf repolist)?
I can do something like this (one repo as an example), but it is a mess.
# add repo. Can I name it (ol8_ovirt45) ? 
dnf config-manager --add-repo https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL8/ovirt45/x86_64

# well ... I want the file to named 'ol8_ovirt45.repo'
ls -l /etc/yum.repos.d/yum.oracle.com_repo_OracleLinux_OL8_ovirt45_x86_64.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 229 Dec 12 12:47 /etc/yum.repos.d/yum.oracle.com_repo_OracleLinux_OL8_ovirt45_x86_64.repo

# well ... I want the repo to be named 'ol8_ovirt45'
dnf repolist | grep 45
yum.oracle.com_repo_OracleLinux_OL8_ovirt45_x86_64 created by dnf config-manager from https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL8/ovirt45/x86_64

# I want the repo to be named 'ol8_ovirt45' out of the box. 
cat /etc/yum.repos.d/yum.oracle.com_repo_OracleLinux_OL8_ovirt45_x86_64.repo
[yum.oracle.com_repo_OracleLinux_OL8_ovirt45_x86_64]
name=created by dnf config-manager from https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL8/ovirt45/x86_64
baseurl=https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL8/ovirt45/x86_64
enabled=1

Are we supposed to handcraft the *.repo files coming from Oracle Linux yum server or is there a better way to do this? Is there an oracle package I can install that will configure my needed repos?
PS! I have manged to install OLVM45, but I would like to avoid handcrafting files and sections in /etc/yum.repos.d/
Thank you!
